# [ milli | micro | nano ]second granularity using tv_usec or tv_nsec

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project, and I need to need a finer granularity than whole second (i.e. time()). I was looking through opengroup.org and I notice there are data structures with memebers tv_usec and tv_nsec.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
      struct timespec ts;
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
      printf("%lis %lins\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);

      return 0;
}


test.cpp(5) : error C2079: 'ts' uses undefined struct 'main::timespec'
test.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'CLOCK_REALTIME' : undeclared identifier
test.cpp(6) : error C3861: 'clock_gettime': identifier not found
```

Is there an easy way to get a high precision time value by using the standard lib? I don't actually need high accuracy, but I do need increments for relative time.

Comment: What operating system are you working on?

Comment: compiles here... it's for POSIX systems.. are you using windows or something else?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I'm using Windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who gave an answer, here is the Windows equivalent of the LINUX/UNIX answer...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (void) {
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
printf("%lis %lins\n", st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);

return 0;
}
```

EDIT: You may also want to check GetTickCount(), but I think it comes at a CPU cost.

Answer (score 5):

In C++11, `#include <chrono>` and use the [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) (also available from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/libs/chrono/)).

In Posix, you can use [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gettimeofday.html) to get a microsecond timestamp, or [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) for nanosecond resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following code I wrote for profiling. There you will find the call for ns timestamps in a linux environment. For another environment you might need to replace CLOCK_MONOTONIC

```
#ifndef PROFILER_H
#define PROFILER_H

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <QString>

class Profiler
{
  public:
    Profiler(QString const& name);
    long measure() const;

    long measureNs() const;
    double measureMs() const;
    double measureS() const;
    void printNs() const;
    void printMs() const;
    void printS() const;
  private:
    QString mName;
    timespec mTime;
};

#endif // PROFILER_H

#include "profiler.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

Profiler::Profiler(QString const& name):mName(name){
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &mTime); // Works on Linux
}


long int Profiler::measureNs() const{
  timespec end;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end); // Works on Linux 
  long int diff = (end.tv_sec-mTime.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + (end.tv_nsec - mTime.tv_nsec);
  assert(diff>0);
  return diff;
}

double Profiler::measureMs() const{
  return measureNs()/1000000.0;
}

double Profiler::measureS() const{
  return measureMs()/1000.0;
}

void Profiler::printNs() const{
  qDebug() << mName << "Time elapsed:" << measureNs() << "ns";
}

void Profiler::printMs() const{
  qDebug() << mName << "Time elapsed:" << measureMs() << "ms";
}

void Profiler::printS() const{
  qDebug() << mName << "Time elapsed:" << measureS() << "S";
}
```